# How can I add keywords in the details tab of file properties in PDF files

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pdf, windows-server-2012, acrobat

How can I add keywords here on this tab:

[image]

I want to achieve a feature like Windows Word has it where we can add keywords and it shows up here and then we can search in explorer.

How can I add that feature to my tool of PDF?

Ideally I would want to update the keywords as user is updating tags in Acrobat PDF.

Is this possible? And if yes then please suggest how. I am looking for a direction but unable to find this in Google.

Answer (score 1):

### I. Doing it manually

You can add these keywords by editing the PDF source code.

1. First prepare the PDF for the editor by uncompressing its compressed contents:

   ```
   qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable input.pdf uncompressed.pdf
   ```

   This requires the installation of the command line tool **[QPDF](http://qpdf.sf.net/)**.

   Other command line tools that could achieve similar results are: `podofouncompress` and `mutool clean -d`.
2. Now open `uncompressed.pdf` in a text editor which is able to handle files which may still contain some binary byte sections.
3. Locate the `/Info` dictionary. *(Hint: at the very end of your file there will be a `trailer`, containing an entry like `/Info 34 0 R`. This means the `/Info` dictionary is in PDF object number 34)*.

   Search for `34 0 obj`. You have now found the `/Info` dictionary.
4. The `/Info` dictionary will contain entries such as:

   ```
    /Author (Kurt Pfeifle)
    /Creator (MS Word 2010)
    /CreationDate (D:20150304000000+01'00')
   ```
5. Add your desired Keywords by adding an extra line into the dictionary:

   ```
    /Keywords (keyword1, keyword2, blah blubb, foo, bar)
   ```

   Save your edits.
6. Now re-compress your edited PDF:

   ```
   qpdf uncompressed.pdf input-modified.pdf
   ```

   You'll probably notice a few warnings being displayed, about the xref being repaired. They are harmless.

### II. Doing it with Ghostscript

You can also add keywords by running the original PDF through **[Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)**, which will create a completely new PDF from the input.

1. First prepare a special text file `keywords.txt` with the following contents:

   ```
   [ /Keywords (keyword1, keyword2, blah blubb, foo, bar)
     /DOCINFO pdfmark
   ```
2. Then run a Ghostscript command:

   ```
   gs -o with-keywords.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite input.pdf keywords.txt
   ```
3. You could skip the creation of the text file (step 1. above) entirely, and provide all keywords on the Ghostscript command line also:

   ```
   gs -o with-keywords.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
      -c "[/Keywords (keyword1, keyword2, blah blubb, foo, bar)" \
      -c "/DOCINFO pdfmark" \
      -f input.pdf
   ```

   or even

   ```
   gs -o with-keywords.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
      -c "[/Keywords(keyword1, keyword2, blah blubb, foo, bar)/DOCINFO pdfmark" \
      -f input.pdf
   ```

### III. Doing it with Adobe Acrobat (Pro)

Adobe Acrobat (Pro) provides a GUI to simply edit in the keywords.

1. Go to menu *'File' -> 'Properties...'*
2. Open the tab titled with *'Description'*
3. Add your keywords into the field named *'Keywords:'*.

### IV. Making Windows PDF-aware

You did not name the version of Windows you are on.

AFAIK, in the olden times of Windows XP/2000,  you needed to install a third-party *Windows Shell Extension* or a *Windows iFilter* in order to get access to the metadata of PDF files.

This enabled add-ons then allowed to display "Keywords" and "Pages" columns in Windows Explorer windows whith the *details* view mode.

**[Debenu](http://www.debenu.com/products/desktop/debenu-pdf-benubird/)** provides such a Windows shell extension too (free, like "gratis").

I also seem to remember that Adobe Acrobat and other PDF software installed such an extension by default.

Of course, while one of these may be *installed* on your Windows, it could as well have been *disabled* by an admin.

So better check that also.

Comment: That doesn't work. I am looking to also integrate this in the Windows search. I added keywords using Acrobat Pro but when I try to search those keywords are not searchable: http://gyazo.com/0630f6b8e3a46e512231790d836cead7 Please see how Word has tags and are searchable in explorer using *keywords:*

Comment: @Jack: ***What*** doesn't work?  ***(a)*** Adding keywords to PDF manually? -- ***(b)*** Adding keywords to PDF with Ghostscript? -- ***(c)*** Adding keywords to PDF with Acrobat? -- ***(d)*** All methods to add keywords worked -- but Windows Explorer doesn't play along nicely and declines to display them?

Comment: d) Those keywords don't show when I try to do windows explorer search using "tags:"